# Luasocket custom headers, 404 turns to 301

Tags: sockets, http-headers, lua, luasocket

My previous question was about fetching page title in **lua** using the `socket.http` module. The question [lies here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10306489/1190388). Previously, youtube pages led me to a **404 error page**. Based on [MattJ's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10308671/1190388), I put up custom `HOST` header for the request. This is what I did and what was the result:

### Code

```
header = { host= "youtube.com" }
local result,b,c,h = http.request{ url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eT40eV7OiI", headers = header }
print ( result, b, c, h )
for k,v in pairs(c) do print(k,v) end
```

### Result

```
1   301 table: 0047D430 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
x-content-type-options  nosniff
content-length  0
expires Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
cache-control   no-cache
connection  close
location    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eT40eV7OiI
content-type    text/html; charset=utf-8
date    Sat, 28 Apr 2012 04:26:21 GMT
server  wiseguy/0.6.11
```

As far as I was able to understand from this, the error is basically because of `X-Content-Type-Options` valued `nosniff`. Reading its [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_response_headers), I got to know that *the only defined value, "nosniff", prevents Internet Explorer from MIME-sniffing a response away from the declared content-type*.

---

Please help me so that I can use custom proxy and fetch the youtube(and some other sites, as mentioned in the previous question) title from their body. Here is the complete LUA file I currently have:

```
local http = require "socket.http"
http.PROXY="http://<proxy address here>:8080"
header = { host= "youtube.com" }
local result,b,c,h = http.request{ url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eT40eV7OiI", headers = header }
print ( result, b, c, h )
for k,v in pairs(c) do print(k,v) end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this line should be changed:

```
 header = { host= "youtube.com" }
```

To:

```
 header = { host= "www.youtube.com" }
```

After that, works for me.

Comment: Nope, I tried with `www` in the **host** name too, the result was yet the same.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is to [install luasec](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec/) and to use ssl.https module to do the request.

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37555539/2764551) by [Paul Kulchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442917/paul-kulchenko)!

Example:

```
-- luasec version 0.4.2
require("ssl")
require("https")
-- ssl.https.request(...)
```