# luaSocket HTTP requests always respond with a redirect (301 or 302)

Tags: http, redirect, lua, luasocket

I use LuaForWindows (latest version) and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360632) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306489) answer and everything i could find in the [mailinglist](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/) of lua-users.org. What ever I try (most) sites only respond with either 301 or 302. I have created an example batch script which downloads (some) of the OpenGL 2.1 Reference from their man pages.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "SKIP=5" %%# IN ( %~fs0 ) DO lua -l socket.http -e "print(socket.http.request('https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/%%#.xml'))"
GOTO:EOF

glAccum
glActiveTexture
glAlphaFunc
glAreTexturesResident
glArrayElement
glAttachShader
glBegin
glBeginQuery
glBindAttribLocation
glBindBuffer
```

the most important part is this:

```
print(require('socket.http').request('https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glAccum.xml')) -- added glAccum so you can run it
```

This ALWAYS returns a 301. This also happens to me when downloading from other random pages. (I dont note them so I cant give a list, but i happened to find out some of them use cloudflare.)

If i write an equivalent downloader in Java using [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [openConnection()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) it wont redirect.

I already tried folowing the redirect manually (setting refferer and stuff) and using [the 'generic' way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306489#10308671). As most of the tips stated in other answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `socket.http`, but try to access `https` URL. luasocket doesn't handle HTTPS protocol, so it sends a request to the default port 80 instead and gets a redirect to HTTPS link (same link); this goes for several times (as the URL doesn't really change), and in the end luasocket gives up producing the message.

The solution is to [install luasec](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec/) and to use `ssl.https` module to do the request.

Comment: Thank you! As those things I tested were quite old I always tested http. Nowdays everyTHING is https (or converting to) and those neatly hidden things are easy to miss out... like an s at the end of http in the suggestions. I also should point out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306489 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360632