# read html page in Lua

Tags: http, lua

I want to read this page using Lua
https://smart-lab.ru/dividends/index/order_by_t2_date/desc/

I can do it with python. It reads all I want:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
txt=urlopen("https://smart-lab.ru/dividends/index/order_by_t2_date/desc/", timeout=10).readlines()
print(txt)
```

But I cannot do it with lua:

```
require "socket"
http = require 'socket.http'
local address = "https://smart-lab.ru/dividends/index/order_by_t2_date/desc/"
local body = http.request(address)
```

It prints only this:
[image]

How can I download this page in Lua?
Not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555226/luasocket-http-requests-always-respond-with-a-redirect-301-or-302).

because my request doesn't reurn nor 301 nor 302

Comment: Possible duplicate of [luaSocket HTTP requests always respond with a redirect (301 or 302)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555226/luasocket-http-requests-always-respond-with-a-redirect-301-or-302)

Comment: @Carcigenicate actually the default behavior of the library already follows 301's.  The issue is that the request is for https:.. and this causes an internal loop because a different library is required to handle https.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No worries, you were just trying to help, and I appreciate that effort

Comment: I highly recommend to use [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) for HTTP requests. Lua socket combined with luasec makes problems with actual HTTP- and TLS-versions.

Comment: You could also shell out to `curl`, which is provided by most Windows and Linux distributions.

Answer (score 2):

for `https` links, you need to use `ssl` library,
try this code:

```
local https = require('ssl.https')
local url = 'https://smart-lab.ru/dividends/index/order_by_t2_date/desc/'
local resp = {}
local body, code, headers = https.request{ url = url,  sink = ltn12.sink.table(resp) }   
if code~=200 then 
    print("Error: ".. (code or '') ) 
    return 
end
print("Status:", body and "OK" or "FAILED")
print("HTTP code:", code)
print("Response headers:")
if type(headers) == "table" then
  for k, v in pairs(headers) do
    print(k, ":", v)        
  end
end
print( table.concat(resp) )
```

Comment: Please help me to install this library. luarocks doesn't help. Error: Could not find expected file openssl/ssl.h for OPENSSL -- you may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or set the OPENSSL_DIR variable. I found library here "https://github.com/brunoos/luasec" but I don't know how to install it.

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Using luarocks you install luasec:

```
luarocks install luasec
```

This will then allow you to require ssl.https

luasec depends on having Openssl development package installed on your system.  The way to do this depends greatly on your OS.