# Invoke Rest api end point in LUA

Tags: lua

I need to invoke a Rest API endpoint from my Lua script. How can I do that?
For example, I am able to invoke the endpoint by the below curl command:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ParseAppID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKey" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

The same I wanted in Lua.

Comment: I'm using [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) for this.

Comment: [Lua*](http://lua.org/about.html#name)

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of options

- [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/)
- [Lua-HTTP](https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http)
- [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3)
- [(probably more)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=http+request+over+Lua&t=canonical&ia=software)

All of them are slightly different, but all of them can call your API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Lua by itself cannot call that endpoint, since the standard networking doesn't support https. You will need to use a 3rd-party library, I suggest Lua-cURL. You will need to download and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`luasocket`](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/):

```lua
local http = require('socket.http')
local ltn12 = require('ltn12')

local r = {}
http.request {
    url = 'https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1000000',
    headers = {['x-accept'] = 'donates'},
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(r)
}
print(r[1])
```

Comment: Please note that many versions of luasocket (including 3.0-rc1 in Debian Bullseye) [silently downgrades https to http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555226/luasocket-http-requests-always-respond-with-a-redirect-301-or-302). Fixed in 3.0.0 proper according to [MSGH#229](https://github.com/lunarmodules/luasocket/issues/229).