# Access REST API via lua script

Tags: api, post, lua, get, response

Is there way to access rest api with pure lua script

GET / POST both way need to access and display response

i already tried

```
    local api = nil
    local function iniit()
    if api == nil then
      -- body
      api = require("http://api.com")
            .create()
            .on_get(function ()
                return {name = "Apple",
                        id = 12345}

            end)
        end
     end
```

Comment: What Lua library are you using?  Where I can read the doc on `.on_get`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff , i'm completely noob for lua, so dont know .on_get is a library or not.  Anyone can help ?

Comment: If the REST API is documented in OpenAPI/Swagger, you may want to try using OpenAPI Generator to generate the Lua API client instead: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65783685/52499).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux , mac we can easily install luarocks , and then we can install curl package. It's easiest way to unix like os.

```
-- HTTP Get
local curl = require('curl')

curl.easy{
  url = 'api.xyz.net?a=data',
  httpheader = {
    "X-Test-Header1: Header-Data1",
    "X-Test-Header2: Header-Data2",
  },
  writefunction = io.stderr -- use io.stderr:write()
}
:perform()
:close()
```

In windows i faced several problems. Cant install luarocks correctly. then luarock install command not work correctl, etc..

In first dwnload lua from official site, and then create structure like (below web site)

http://fuchen.github.io/dev/2013/08/24/install-luarocks-on-windows/

then i download **lua luadist**
**http://luadist.org/**

then i got same structure **luadist** extracted folder and **lua** folder.

merged **luadist** folder and **lua** folder
Finaly we can use http.soket

```
local http=require("socket.http");

local request_body = [[login=user&password=123]]
local response_body = {}

local res, code, response_headers = http.request{
    url = "api.xyz.net?a=data",
    method = "GET", 
    headers = 
      {
          ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
          ["Content-Length"] = #request_body;
      },
      source = ltn12.source.string(request_body),
      sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body),
}

print(res)
print(code)

if type(response_headers) == "table" then
  for k, v in pairs(response_headers) do 
    print(k, v)
  end
end

print("Response body:")
if type(response_body) == "table" then
  print(table.concat(response_body))
else
  print("Not a table:", type(response_body))
end
```

IF YOU DO THESE STEPS CORRECTLY , THIS WILL BE WORK 1000% SURE